# Ejecutar jar Spring Boot desde Shell Script

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, shell-script

estoy haciendo un proyecto en Spring Boot que se ejecute desde Shell Script, esto ya lo he hecho con una clase sencilla de java, aquí un ejemplo de mi Shell Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

CLASSPATH=/home/proyecto/PRUEBA/bin/
PATH=/home/proyecto/JDK/jdk1.8.0_231/bin/java

$PATH -cp $CLASSPATH MiClase
```

Y en mi clase Java:

```
public class MiClase {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hola mundo desde Java");
        
    }

}
```

Quise hacer lo mismo utilizando Spring Boot, pero me dice que **no encuentra la clase main**, cabe mencionar que el ejemplo está en el paquete por default, a diferencia de Spring Boot que ya genera un paquete y una clase que usaré para imprimir los datos por consola. Mis preguntas son:

1. ¿Como podría hacer para ejecutarla como en el ejemplo?
2. ¿Cómo le puedo mandar parámetros al main para que me ejecute métodos que reciben argumentos?

Ejemplo ejecuto el shell:
./prueba.sh parametro1 parametro2 parametro3
En java dentro del main

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        usuario.buscar(parametro1, parametro2, parametro3);
}
```

Agradezco su apoyo, ¡Saludos!

Comment: Hola, que yo tengo entendido para ejecutar la aplicación, necesitas usar ```maven```,añadir sus depedencias  en el ```pom.xml``` , a continuación compilar  y  empaquetar la aplicación para luego ser lanzada. Ejemplo: ```java -jar target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar```

Comment: Qué tal Guillermo, efectivamente, así es como lo hago, todo lo que mencionas de Spring ya está, dependencias, empaquetado, etc. El detalle es que al ejecutarlo dice que no encuentra la calse Main, gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: ¿Tienes incluida la anotación correspondiente? ¿Estas usando @SpringBootApplication  en tu clase principal?

Comment: Así es, el main tiene la anotación @SpringBootApplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la forma de hacerlo detalladamente sería así:
En el shell colocamos

```
java -jar ruta/donde/está/la/carpeta/target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Tal vez aparezcan dos archivos .jar hay que utilizar el que termina en SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: Eh, eso fue lo que te indicaron en uno de los comentarios. El problema era la ruta al archivo?

Comment: Así es, porque se genera en otra ruta que no es target y ese no funciona.